# PTIJ: Rules of הלכות שטגן

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I was learning הלכות שַׁטְגָּן with my חברותא and he pointed out in the ספר בשר חמורים that "וכלל הוא שאין שטגן בדבר הסמוי מן העין". What other general rules exist in הלכות שטגן?

---

<sub>Biographical note: The בשר חמורים was written by ר׳ יששכר אייזל אלמוני שליט״א, son of [the באר היטב](/a/5748/170).</sub>

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Could you please [edit] this post to translate the Hebrew terms?

Answer (score 1):

> אמר רב גידל בראשונה כל מאן הוה יכיל לקראי משרבו שקיא לא הוה יכילין קטניא לקראי הקשה ההוא קטן לרבנן והלא תלוי מלתא במוזניא אמרו ליה כל דאלים גבר
>
> Rav Gidel said: Originally, anyone could call. But once the sacks proliferated, the minors could no longer call. A certain minor asked the rabbis: But doesn't the matter depend on the scale? They answered: whoever is strong, dominates.
>
> **לקראי** שטגן: **שקיא** חייתא דאוירא ליציל נפשיא: **לא הוה יכילין קטניא לקראי** מפני דינא דמלכותא שמא יזיק בהן חייתא: **במוזניא** דאפילו קטן דשקל כגדול לא יתזיק: **כל דאלים גבר** דאם הקטן שקל די דלא יתזיק  יגין טובא אשטגנא:‏
>
> **Call** shotgun: **Sacks** Bags of air, to save lives: **Minors could no longer call** due to the law of the kingdom, lest the bag injure them: **On the scale** As even a minor that weighs [as much] as an adult won't be injured: **Whoever is strong, dominates** For if the minor weighs enough to not be injured, he will defend the shotgun well:

Comment: Improvements of the Aramaic and any other improvements, embellishments, and extensions are welcome. I reserve the right to edit further.